# Visualization of Quantum Circuits when using IBM QISKit

Tags: programming, qiskit

I have followed the installation steps, regarding QISKit working environment. For circuit visualization, I've installed latex as in addition to poppler to convert from PDF to images. Afterwards, I followed the example given [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/QISKit/qiskit-tutorial/blob/master/reference/tools/getting_started.ipynb).

I wrote the code and after running, the program run but I didn't get the circuit visualization. I don't know what is the problem, even I have not received any error messages.

So any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the title should be "Visualization of Quantum Circuits when using IBM Qiskit".

Comment: Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! Is it possible to show us a minimal example of the code that displays (or in this case, doesn't display) the problem that you're having with drawing/displaying the circuit?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732603/qcircuit-sty-not-found-when-visualizing-a-qiskit-quantum-scheme

Comment: What is the approximate size of your quantum circuit? How many gates do you try to plot? Does the example you linked works on your setup?

Answer (score 2):

You can find detailed instructions about what you need to install for your particular OS [here](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-tutorial/blob/master/INSTALL.md#5-visualizing-circuits). This visualization uses Latex, so you need to have a latex compiler installed.

Also make sure you have the latest version of Qiskit, as a Windows visualization bug was recently fixed. You can upgrade by doing: 
`pip install -U qiskit`

Within the next couple weeks, Qiskit will have another visualization method that runs purely in Python, hence no other software installations required.