# One-qubit gate results in QISKit

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, programming, qiskit

I found it odd that the result of the action of identity gate (namely a $2\times2$ identity matrix) on a pure state $|0\rangle$ (namely the vector corresponding to the $2\times1$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$) becomes a $2\times2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1+0\cdot i&0+0\cdot i\\0+0\cdot i&1+0\cdot i \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ as I found it [HERE](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/QISKit/qiskit-tutorial/blob/master/reference/tools/quantum_gates_and_linear_algebra.ipynb#Identity-gate) (QISKit tutorial page):
[image]

Also, when one lets for more precision, the result gets odd:

[image]

Why is this? The same thing happens for other gates listed on the page referenced above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you are not asking for the state but the unitary matrix representing the circuit. This is correct and just rounding error.   It looks like you are not using the latest version so I would update.

In the second case are you sure that you don’t have a previous circuit loaded in memory. In that notebook all examples have the same circuit name and it looks like this is a different gate.  If i had to guess it is the u2 example. If this is not the case you have found a bug and please submit an issue and we try to debug it.

I would also change the title as this is not a general quantum computing question to one qubit gates errors in qiskit or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If `job.result().get_data(circuit)` returns the circuit itself, what command gives the result of the operation?

Comment: Regarding the second issue, you're right, I had the version 0.5.3. I updated it and now it's fixed (to version 0.5.4). I just wanted to report an issue related to update: [HERE](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-tutorial/blob/master/INSTALL.md), it says to use `conda env update -f QISKitenv.yml` to upgrade it, but it didn't work for me. This worked [HERE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/visualization-of-quantum-circuits-when-using-ibm-qiskit) `pip install -U qiskit`. Just for future reference.

Comment: Ok then we have not updated the tutorial it’s get_unitary .

Comment: Thanks @Jay. Though `job.result().get_unitary(qc)` doesn't give the result of the action of the gate on the qubit $|0\rangle$. It again gave the unitary matrix (here the identity matrix). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh I see what you want. Change local_unitary_simulator to local_statevecotor_simulator it take the answer you have and times it by a vectors.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it worked, but it did not give $|0\rangle$ back. I expected the result of the action of the identity operator on $|0\rangle$ be itself, though it was {'statevector': array([7.07106781e-01+0.j        , 4.32978028e-17+0.70710678j])}. 

The commands are: 
`q = QuantumRegister(1)`
`qc = QuantumCircuit(q)` 
`job = execute(qc, backend='local_statevector_simulator')` 
`job.result().get_data(qc)`     What is the reason for this?

Comment: This does not make sense. I think it’s best to move this to github as an issue.